# Simple between function gives error?

Tags: javascript

I had done this very simple code:

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a,b){
    return this >= a && this < b ? 1 : 0;
};
```

But when testing:

```
5.between(1,10);
```

Gives me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)
  InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM225:875
  InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM225:808
  InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM225:664
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: I know you want and explanation on why 5.between(1,10) doesn't work, and you got your answers.  The thing is you wouldn't get this error if you were to do something by var x = 5; x.between(1, 10);  <<< You should never have to use a constant 5 to execute a function.  If need to, you can declare constant variables and use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript engine is trying to parse `5.` as a floating number and since the token after the `.` is not a valid number, it is failing with the SyntaxError.

To fix this, you can

1. Leave a space after the number

   ```
   console.log(5 .between(1, 10));
   // 1
   ```
2. use parens to explicitly say that `5` itself is a single expression

   ```
   console.log((5).between(1, 10));
   // 1
   ```
3. use double dots like this

   ```
   console.log(5..between(1, 10));
   // 1
   ```

PS: Avoid modifying the prototype of the builtins. You can always build a utility function.

Comment: I'd recommend the second one over the first because the space is non-obvious and someone may think it's a typo and remove it, leading to errors.

Comment: You can also use two dots.

Answer (score 4):

make it

`Number(5).between(1,10);`

**Reason being -** (thanks to [felix-kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for the same)

As per [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals), the decimal point (.) is not optional in the production roles, so it is always considered to be part of the number literal. Basically, 5.toString() is similar to "5"toString(): A literal followed by an identifier.

Which is why `5.toString()` gives the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

just tested `(5).between(1,10);` will also do since it will then be an expression that evaluates to a Number type

```
for (var key in (5) ){ console.log( key " - " (5)[key] ); }
```

outputs

> between - function (a,b){
>       return this >= a && this < b ? 1 : 0; }

Comment: `5 .between(1, 10)` works so I don't think your explanation is correct

Comment: @CodeiSir you maybe right. But I am unable to find anything specific in this spec here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Yep, your explanation is incorrect and seem to conflate syntax (number *literal*) with runtime information (*object*). As example, `var x = 5; x.toString()` works just fine. The part to look at in the spec is http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue .

Comment: @FelixKling I am looking for the part of spec which says that `5.toString()` is treated as floating point and that is why it is failing

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals . As you can see, the decimal point (`.`) is not optional in the production roles, so it is always considered to be part of the number literal. Basically, `5.toString()` is similar to `"5"toString()`: A literal followed by an identifier. The code may *look* ambiguous but for the parser it is clear that the `.` is part of the number literal, it does not denote property access.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, it was hugely helpful. Updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly call any function on an hardcoded number, put it in `(5)`:

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a,b){
    return this >= a && this < b ? 1 : 0;
};

(5).between(1,10);
```